# Linkedin API post not showing up

Tags: rest, api, linkedin-api, posts

I have an API for posting on my Linkedin company page. It works well, I post and see the posts on my admin interface version of the homepage, but if I visit the public version on the company page  the posts sent though the API do not show up. If I post something from the admin interface of Linkedin it show up on the public page as well. Is there a limitation on the posts sent thought API vs posts native on linkedin?

Thanks,

Comment: did you get a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and I am posting the solution it might be useful for others as well. As my app in in development mode it is hosted on a server that has a self signed SSL certificate. While I have added the certificate in my trusted list and i see the target linked page no problem I have released that Linkedin will not display on public profile posts that contain a link it cannot read, BUT it will display them in the admin interface. As soon as I changed the link to http the add displays on the public page as well.